# Azure Resource Manager - How can I change the Resource Group of a Resource?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-management, azure-resource-manager

I've been combing through the Powershell [commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn654592.aspx) trying to figure out how to take my currently deployed Website/SQL Database/Storage account and move them into their own Resource Group.

Is it possible to move Azure "Resources" between Resource Groups? Or do I always have to create new Resources and migrate the data/code into those new Resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now Azure Resource Manager doesn't support moving resources from one group to another. There is also no storage support yet for Azure Resource Manager.

Migration is an important scenario and we're working on to get the experience better.

Guang Yang | PM | Azure

Comment: It seems that storage is now supported - may be you can update your answer?

Comment: You can move resources now (see my answer)

Answer (score 12):

It is now possible to do what you want in PowerShell, I believe.  This blog post provides an overview of how to do it:  http://blog.kloud.com.au/2015/03/24/moving-resources-between-azure-resource-groups/

The features are available as of Azure PowerShell cmdlets v0.8.15.1, I believe.

Comment: If you struggle with PowerShell, you should try out this way: http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2015/05/27/moving-resources-with-arm/

Answer (score 3):

You can move resources by:
 - Navigating to the Resource Group you wish to move resources out of
 - Click "Move" at the top
 - Select the resources you want to move
 - Select the new group to move them into

Answer (score 0):

You can move resources between resource groups using either the ARM REST Api or the Powershell Api

You can find more details here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/